# Ng Prime table thead columns not adjusting width automatically

Tags: angular, css, angular6

I am using Ng Prime Tables and when I have **columns > 3 everything is working fine** but when **I have columns <= 3 its leaving an empty beside to right side** with some width allocated and even in Inspect i cant find any option to change width of columns.

[image]

**Solution 1:** I tried

```
::ng-deep .ui-table table {
    table-layout: auto !important;
}
```

[image]

The output is not satisfactory and its leaving some white space to the right. 
Also the column values are not occupying equal space, need some help guys

**Solution 2: I tried**

```
<p-table [autoLayout]="true">
```

Same output as Solution 1

**My HTML Code:**

```
<div class="primetable" style="box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgba(69,90,100,.08);">
      <p-table [value]="student"
          [columns]="cols"
          #dt
          class="primetable"
          [paginator]="true"
          [rows]="10" [style]="{width:'100%'}"
          [autoLayout]="true"
          [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,15,20,25]">
          <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
              <div>
                  <input type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      pInputText
                      size="50"
                      placeholder="Search Data Here"
                      (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')"
                      style="width:auto">
              </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="header"
              let-columns>
              <tr>
                  <th style="padding: 15px 15px;color: #1e6bb8;background: white"
                      *ngFor="let col of columns">{{col.header}}</th>
              </tr>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="body"
              let-student
              let-i="rowIndex"
              >
              <tr [pSelectableRow]="student">
                  <td >{{i+1}}</td>
                  <td>{{student.regnum}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </ng-template>
      </p-table>
```

**TS Code:**

```
this.cols = [
      { field: 'S.No', header: 'S.No' },
      { field: 'regnum', header: 'Regnum' },
      { field: 'attendance', header: 'Attendance' }
  ];
```

Thanks in Advance, Happy Coding

Comment: try [style]="{width:'100%'}" in the p-table tag..

Comment: Not working @Sreemat

Comment: [autoLayout]="true" this one..

Comment: Tried that too bruh, same output as solution1

Comment: can you paste some html code here

Comment: I edited my code